# Mangled Markdown leads to unclosed italics in Chrome

Tags: bug, markdown, google-chrome, markdown-rendering, webkit

[A question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15029313/1) was posted on Stack Overflow with [this Markdown source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b093555e-b013-4410-a335-6293c7972cd8/view-source):

```
Write a program to print the following pattern:
* * * * * * * * *
* * * *   * * * *
* * *       * * *
* *           * *
*               *
* *           * *
* * *       * * *
* * * *   * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
```

Obviously this is incorrectly formatted and it yields a monstrosity of nested lists. But grotesque as it is, there's a bug in the rendered HTML. The HTML has improperly nested `<em>` tags. IE and Firefox are okay, but in Chrome it leaves italics open for the rest of the page. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Chrome rendering]

And here is the questionable HTML:

```
<p><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><em></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li></em></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><em></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li></em></li>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><em></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li></em></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li><ul>
<li>*
<hr></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></p>
```

Answer (score 12):

<sub>(This isn't a "this is fixed" answer; I'm just describing the problem for now).</sub>

I learned something new today. Look at [HTMLTreeBuilder.cpp](http://src.chromium.org/multivm/trunk/webkit/Source/WebCore/html/parser/HTMLTreeBuilder.cpp) in the Chromium source and find the method called `callTheAdoptionAgency`. I'm serious.

The algorithm that checks what formatting element is closed by a closing HTML tag list limited to a certain search depth for performance reasons. And thus when a closing `</em>` appears deeply nested inside nine `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, the browser will essentially ignore it. Our tag balancer does not have this restriction though, so it thinks the `</em>` is correctly closed.

These depth restrictions are actually [described in the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tree-construction.html#parsing-main-inbody), so we can't really blame Chrome for this. Then again, this spec also says this:

> When the user agent is to apply the rules for the "in body" insertion mode, the user agent must handle the token as follows: [...]
>
> **↪ An end tag whose tag name is "sarcasm"**
>              Take a deep breath, then act as described in the "any other end tag" entry below.