# Markdown-Quotes inside HTML are breaking the output

Tags: bug, markdown, design

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/179086#179086) post appears totally messed up for me. It uses many blockquotes, that apparently lead to the link beeing spread all over the `post-text`, including the *flag*, *edit*, *link* and *answered/edited at* URLs:

[image: The link inside the answer spreads all over the answer's div]

The answer's text uses markdown-quotes inside a HTML-tag. I guess this somehow messes up the output...

```
<a href="http://google.ca">
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><h1>THIS IS A REALLY BIG BUTTON!</h1>
</a>
```

This is what Firebug shows:

[image: The answers HTML markup]

As you can see, the link from the question is spread over the whole answer.

Comment: Very similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168656/mangled-markdown-leads-to-unclosed-italics-in-chrome; probably the same or almost the same issue (see my answer there)